# SQL How to SUM rows in second column if first column contain

Tags: sql

View of a table

| ID | kWh |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 2 | 8 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 |

I want to recive

| ID | kWh |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 32 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 12 |

The table itself is more complex and larger. But the point is this. How can this be done? And I can't know in advance the ID numbers of the first column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.ID,SUM(T.KWH)SUM_KWH
FROM YOUR_TABLE T
GROUP BY T.ID
```

Do you need this one?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. But I found out my problem. It was a lot of inner joins and in one of them was a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your database name is 'testdb' and table name is 'table1'.

```
    SELECT * FROM testdb.table1;
    SELECT id, SUM(kwh) AS "kwh2"
    FROM stack.table1
    WHERE id = 1
```

keep running the query will all (ids). you will get output.

By following this query you will get desired output.

Hope this helps.